# What are some fonts where o and a look similar?

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for fonts where there are few differences between lower case Os and As, like the title suggests. There is indeed a reason for this.

Comment: Do you have any example? What would you need that for?

Comment: Do you mean like ‘α’ as opposed to ‘a’? Some serif fonts have that style of letter available in the italic version of the font, or as a separate glyph in the normal version of the font. Also there are many fonts which contain the Greek letter alpha glyph.

Comment: I'm looking to make "dark" and "dork" look similar.